# Can't open TornadoFx Jar application that created in mac os and opend on Windows

Tags: tornadofx

I created a simple TornadoFX application using Kotlin.

This is my main class

```
class MyApp: App(MyView::class)

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    launch<MyApp>(args)
}
```

and this is my ui class

```
class MyView: View() {
    override val root = vbox {
        button("Press me")
        label("Waiting")
    }
}
```

When i try to generate a .jar file with artifacts
On my mac the jar file opens, but when i try to open it on windows i'm getting an error

```
WARNING: Unsupported JavaFX configuration: classes were loaded from 'unnamed module @10c98295'
Graphics Device initialization failed for :  d3d, sw
Error initializing QuantumRenderer: no suitable pipeline found
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error initializing QuantumRenderer: no suitable pipeline found
        at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer.getInstance(QuantumRenderer.java:283)
        at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.init(QuantumToolkit.java:253)
        at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.getToolkit(Toolkit.java:268)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.startup(PlatformImpl.java:291)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.startup(PlatformImpl.java:163)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.startToolkit(LauncherImpl.java:659)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:679)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$2(LauncherImpl.java:196)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1623)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error initializing QuantumRenderer: no suitable pipeline found
        at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer$PipelineRunnable.init(QuantumRenderer.java:95)
        at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer$PipelineRunnable.run(QuantumRenderer.java:125)
        ... 1 more
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: No toolkit found
        at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.getToolkit(Toolkit.java:280)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.startup(PlatformImpl.java:291)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.startup(PlatformImpl.java:163)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.startToolkit(LauncherImpl.java:659)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:679)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$2(LauncherImpl.java:196)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1623)

C:\Users\vboxrd\Desktop>java -jar demo.jar
Error: JavaFX runtime components are missing, and are required to run this application

C:\Users\vboxrd\Desktop>java -jar demo.jar
Error: JavaFX runtime components are missing, and are required to run this application
```

This is my .pom file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <artifactId>Testing</artifactId>
    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>consoleApp</name>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <kotlin.code.style>official</kotlin.code.style>
        <kotlin.compiler.jvmTarget>11</kotlin.compiler.jvmTarget>
    </properties>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>mavenCentral</id>
            <url>https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src/main/kotlin</sourceDirectory>
        <testSourceDirectory>src/test/kotlin</testSourceDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
                <artifactId>kotlin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.8.20</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>compile</id>
                        <phase>compile</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>test-compile</id>
                        <phase>test-compile</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>test-compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
                <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.0.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>MyMainApp</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.22.2</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.22.2</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.6.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>MainKt</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
                <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.0.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>MyMainApp</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <release>11</release>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>


        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
            <artifactId>kotlin-test-junit5</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.20</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <version>5.8.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
            <artifactId>kotlin-stdlib-jdk8</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.20</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>7.7.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>4.9.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.appium</groupId>
            <artifactId>java-client</artifactId>
            <version>8.4.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>7.7.1</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.aventstack</groupId>
            <artifactId>extentreports</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.9</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>no.tornado</groupId>
            <artifactId>tornadofx</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.20</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
            <artifactId>kotlin-stdlib-jdk8</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.31</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- JavaFX dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
            <version>19</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
            <version>19</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jetbrains.kotlinx/kotlinx-coroutines-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlinx</groupId>
            <artifactId>kotlinx-coroutines-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.1</version>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.200</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlinx</groupId>
            <artifactId>kotlinx-coroutines-android</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.1</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

</project>
```

I tried to add a vm option to the configuration but the project didnt comile after it

I'm getting a warning when compilig the project:

```
WARNING: Unsupported JavaFX configuration: classes were loaded from 'unnamed module @3d1e2ee6'
```